Rs-485 and Modbus Master
I am trying to communicate with a battery charge controller via RS-485 ModBus RTU half-duplex communication. I am using a Particle Argon and this RS-485 transciever. I can see that the Tx packet is correct and being sent. However, I am getting no response. The charge controller is powered separately so only the A,B, and GND lines are connected.

#include "Particle.h"

SYSTEM_MODE(SEMI_AUTOMATIC);
SYSTEM_THREAD(ENABLED);

//instantiate ModbusMaster object as slave ID 1
ModbusMaster node(1);
unsigned long interval = 0;
unsigned long base_T = 1000;
const int addr = 0x30A0;

void idle() {
  delay(10); // in case slave only replies after 10ms
}

void setup() {
  // initialize Modbus communication baud rate
  node.begin(9600);
  node.enableTXpin(D4); //D7 is the pin used to control the TX enable pin of RS485 driver
  node.enableDebug(); //Print TX and RX frames out on Serial. Beware, enabling this messes up the timings for RS485 Transactions, causing them to fail.
  node.idle(idle); //function gets called in the idle time between transmission of data and response from slave

  Serial.begin(9600);
  // while(!Serial.available()) Particle.process();
  Serial.println("Starting Modbus Transaction:");
}

void loop() {
  uint8_t j, result;
  uint16_t data[10];

  if (millis() - interval > base_T) {
    interval = millis();
    result = node.readInputRegisters(addr, 1);

    // do something with data if read is successful
    if (result == node.ku8MBSuccess) {
      Serial.print("Success, Received data: ");
      for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        data[j] = node.getResponseBuffer(j);
        Serial.print(data[j], HEX);
        Serial.print(" ");
      }
      Serial.println("");
      base_T = 1000;
    } else {
      Serial.print("Failed, Response Code: ");
      Serial.print(result);
      Serial.print(" - ");
      Serial.print(result, HEX);
      Serial.println("");
      base_T = 5000; //if failed, wait for bit longer, before retrying!
    }
  }
}

Does anyone experience using this transceiver or debugging the RS-485 bus? I've used a logic analyzer to confirm that the transmitted packet looks as expect leaving the micro but am not sure what to expected the A,B lines of the RS-485 transceiver to look like.

It's been ages, but with RS485 don't you have to disable the TX pin in order to receive anything? I mean, enable when sending, but then disable it.

@500-InternalServerError the node.enableTXpin(D4); should configure the ModbusMaster to do that (pin D4 high before writing). @afry have you verified that the "battery charge controller" responds to a Modbus request from a known good source (i.e. a PC)? (from the question it's not clear where the issue is, so I'd suggest checking each component individually).
